# Can I use southeast asian fish sauce as a marinade?

Tags: marinade, vietnamese-cuisine

I have been using Southeast Asian fish sauce ( its Vietnamese variant called "nước mắm" to be precise ) to marinade meat which I would then fry. From the narrow observation I made though the Vietnamese seem to use it solely to dip the food in it. Is my usage really that unusual?

Comment: Welcome! This site is about cooking, not health (see the [faq]), so I removed that part of your question. What remains seems like a pretty trivial question, so feel free to edit further if it's not all you meant to ask!

Comment: @Jefromi Hi. I understand the principle, but my question was more about if it is not the case that such frying would cause some chemical reaction that would make such practice a bad idea, not about classic concern - how healthy my dish would be. :)

Comment: Ah, I see. That didn't really occur to me, because in general, foods that are made out of normal ingredients (meat or plants) do not become unsafe when you cook them. I don't see why fish sauce would be an exception, but you're welcome to edit a food safety question back in if you're concerned!

Comment: My mother (vietnamese) used fish sauce on pretty much everything in the kitchen. It can sub in for salt in a lot of dishes and it works well as a marinade. I like to season my fried eggs with tons of it (with a bit of sugar to even it out).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not unusual at all. See [this page from Vietnamese-American cooks](http://cheftindy.com/blog/category/chicken/) for examples where nuoc-mam is used to marinate chicken, or just type

> nuoc mam marinade

in Google :)

There are a lot of examples, including [fish](http://www.asiarecipe.com/viesauce.html#lemon), [chicken](http://cheftindy.com/blog/category/chicken/), [beef](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%BAn_b%C3%B2_Hu%E1%BA%BF), or even [mango](http://www.flickr.com/photos/loic_tasquier/4343344227/) marinated (as well as [dipped](http://gastronomyblog.com/2008/04/08/scenes-eating-in-district-4/), of course) with nuoc-mam (and most of the time lemongrass), and a fair share of them are recipes by 'natives' from South-East Asia, not only fusion food addicts (even if [you can be both](http://indonesiaeats.com/greek-swordfish-salad-with-vietnamese-nuoc-mam-cham-and-mustard/)!).
Some salads like goi tom or goi ga also involve nuoc mam marinade.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! Especially for those great examples :)

Comment: You're welcome! I added a few links now that I am allowed post more than two. Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

> Verb - marinate = to pickle in brine, sea water. Marine.
>
> Noun - marinade = the liquid used as medium to marinate.

Wikipedia on "Fish Sauce":

> Fish sauce is an amber-colored liquid extracted from the fermentation of fish with **sea salt**.

From the definition/etymology of the word of "marinate" - - -> of course, you can. It's your kitchen and your preferences for flavour.

I am sure that marinating only flavours the outer layers of meat and you should cut gashes into the meat to allow the marinade to penetrate.

Rather, your question should be,

> how do I marinate with Vietnamese/Thai fish sauce?

I think, in fact, you could even ask the question,

> How do I marinate meat with Australian Vegemite or British Marmite?

I think to preserve and complement the fishy fragrance (most people would prefer to call it fishy odour),

- the marinade is retained to be part of the gravy.
- you should have garlic powder and chopped scallions mixed in the marinade (the fish sauce).
- little bit of black vinegar
- I did try mixing in curry powder, cinnamon.

And then the marination graduates into a marinating/poaching process on the same pan by turning the temperature up. What I am describing is a form of poaching which I do at low temp grilling in an enclosed oven.

I marinate at 100F for a couple of hours and then turning up the temperature to poach at 200 F over another couple of hours using various appendices/apparatus to elevate the meat (chicken wings/quarters) to as close to the oven elements as possible without touching them. About an inch of clearance.

And finally turning the temperature up to 350F for 30 minutes to "attempt" to achieve the occasionally surprisingly crispy skin

Turning the meat over at opportune times. The slow grilling can produce pretty amazing crisp on the skin. (However, there was once when the salmon became dry and fibrous after leaving it in there for too long.)

I am sure there is a lot of room for improvement in my culinary timing skills. And I've only tried poaching poultry and salmon. I did destroy a few pretty herring by trying out the same process. And turkey wings/quarters wouldn't even get cooked or amenable to absorbing any marinade under the same process.